# Вывод данных из файла

Tags: c++, алгоритм, файлы, структуры

Имеется часть кода:

```
struct St
{
    string Name;
    int math;
    int phys;
    int inf;
    int chem;
    int dateOfBirth;
    int group;
    double ball;
} Students;

void showNeedableStudents() {
    ifstream file1("list.txt");
    cout << "Enter the needable group: " << endl;
    int input_group;
    cin >> input_group;
    cout << "Enter the math mark u want: " << endl;
    int input_math;
    cin >> input_math;
    cout << "Enter the phys mark you need: " << endl;
    int input_phys;
    cin >> input_phys;
    string buf;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\t\tFound students:" << endl;
    while (getline(file1, buf)) {
        file1 >> Students.Name >> Students.math >> Students.inf >> Students.phys >> Students.chem >> Students.dateOfBirth >> Students.group >> Students.ball;
        if (Students.group == input_group && Students.math == input_math && Students.phys == input_phys) {
            cout << Students.Name << " " << Students.math << " " << Students.inf << " " << Students.phys << " " << Students.chem << " " << Students.dateOfBirth << " " << Students.group << " " << Students.ball << endl;
        }
    }

    file1.close();

}
```

Файл List:

```
Sergei 10 10 10 10 2000 714302 10
Vasya 10 2 10 2 1999 714302 10
Petya 2 3 4 5 1998 714301 5.5
```

Задача - считывание данных о студентах из файла и если их оценки совпадают с введенными, то вывести данные на консоль. Однако при вводе оценок 10, 10 и группы 714302 выводит на экран только данные о втором ученике, причём 2 раза. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
while (getline(file1, buf)) {
    file1 >> Students.Name >> Students.math >> Students.inf 
          >> Students.phys >> Students.chem >> Students.dateOfBirth 
          >> Students.group >> Students.ball;
```

вот этим кодом:

```
while(file1 >> Students.Name >> Students.math >> Students.inf
      >> Students.phys >> Students.chem >> Students.dateOfBirth
      >> Students.group >> Students.ball
     ) {
```

Вы читаете лишнего (так что теряете первого и последнего студентов совсем) - раз, а после выхода на конец файла *все равно пытаетесь читать* (а чтения не происходит) - вот и получаете второго такого же студента в старых неизмененных переменных.

Answer (score 0):

В строке

```
    file1 >> Students.Name >> Students.math >> Students.inf >> Students.phys >> Students.chem >> Students.dateOfBirth >> Students.group >> Students.ball;
```

Вы читаете из файла в структуру, только вот... До этого вы получили одну строку файла в переменную `buf`. Вам нужно читать из данной строки, а не из файла. Сделайте вот так:

```
void showNeedableStudents() {
    ifstream file1("list.txt");
    cout << "Enter the needable group: " << endl;
    int input_group;
    cin >> input_group;
    cout << "Enter the math mark u want: " << endl;
    int input_math;
    cin >> input_math;
    cout << "Enter the phys mark you need: " << endl;
    int input_phys;
    cin >> input_phys;
    string buf;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\t\tFound students:" << endl;
    while (getline(file1, buf)) {
        stringstream myStream(buf);
        myStream >> Students.Name >> Students.math >> Students.inf >> Students.phys >> Students.chem >> Students.dateOfBirth >> Students.group >> Students.ball;
        if (Students.group == input_group && Students.math == input_math && Students.phys == input_phys) {
            cout << Students.Name << " " << Students.math << " " << Students.inf << " " << Students.phys << " " << Students.chem << " " << Students.dateOfBirth << " " << Students.group << " " << Students.ball << endl;
        }
    }

    file1.close();
}
```

Я создаю поток `myStream` из строки, в которую вы получили запись об одном ученике, и из нее уже вычитываю необходимые данные.