# Ошибка сегментации 11 при запуске программы, читающей файл из аргументов main()

Tags: c++

Пишу программу, рассчитывающую волновую функцию для молекулы, параметры которой заданы во входном файле. Начал писать с его чтения. Написал класс, определил базовые методы, скомпилировал, получаю ошибку сегментации, но сходу не могу понять, с чем конкретно она связана. Помогите, пожалуйста, где что стоит исправить, может ещё отредактировать, чтоб компактней и красивей выглядело. Компилятор - Clang 10 из Command Line Tools.
Листинг molecule.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Molecule {
public:
int natom; // количество атомов в молекуле
int charge; // заряд
int multiplicity; // мультиплетность
std::vector<char> atomSymbol; // символ атома по таблице Менделеева, первый столбец входного файла
std::vector<int> atomicNumber; // каждому атому в молекуле присваивается номер
std::vector<std::vector<double> > geom;
void printgeom(); // вывод XYZ геометрии молекулы
void printChargeMultNatoms(); // вывод заряда, мультиплетности, количества атомов и прочей фигни, что мне покажется нужной

Molecule(const char* filename);
~Molecule();
};
```

Листинг molecule.cpp:

```
#include "molecule.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void Molecule::printgeom() {
for(int i=0; i < natom; i++)
std::cout << atomSymbol[i] << geom[i][0] << geom[i][1] << geom[i][2];
}

void Molecule::printChargeMultNatoms() {
std::cout << "Charge is " << charge << std::endl;
std::cout << "Multiplicity is" << multiplicity << std::endl;
std::cout << "Molecule contains " << natom << " atoms." << std::endl;
}

Molecule::Molecule(const char* filename) {
// open input file
std::ifstream inputfile(filename);
assert(inputfile.good());

// чтение заряда и мультиплетности из первой строчки входного файла
inputfile >> charge >> multiplicity;

// read the cartesian geometry, type and number of atoms
for(int i = 0; !inputfile.eof(); i++) {    
inputfile >> atomSymbol[i] >> geom[i][0] >> geom[i][1] >> geom[i][2];
i = atomicNumber[i] + 1;
}
inputfile.close();
natom = geom.size();
}

Molecule::~Molecule() {}
```

Листинг main.cpp:

```
#include "molecule.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

if (argc == 0) { 
std::cout << "No input file was found." << std::endl;
return 1;
}

const char *inputFileName = argv[1];

Molecule input(inputFileName);
input.printChargeMultNatoms();
input.printgeom();

return 0;
}
```

Вид входного файла:

```
0 1
C          1.11988       -0.11356       -0.04893
C         -0.22149        0.53742        0.15390
N         -1.36703       -0.23693       -0.04570
O         -0.39583        1.70537        0.48392
H          1.93813        0.59458        0.13709
H          1.23188       -0.48457       -1.07645
H          1.25795       -0.96373        0.63239
H         -2.27205        0.14808        0.07622
H         -1.29145       -1.18667       -0.31244
```

Сразу скажу, что много копипастил, и в плюсах ещё только начал разбираться.

Comment: Я не приведу готового решения, т.к. задача простая и хочу дать Вам шанс самому сделать улучшения. 1. Я бы рекомендовал заменить `std::vector<char> atomSymbol;`  на `std::string`. По смыслу использования это правильнее. И не забывайте, что имена атомов бывают и из 2 букв. 2. Вам не нужен 2-мерный массив. Вам нужна структура с полями для `atom_name`, `x`,`y`,`z` и потом простой массив таких структур (`vector`). 3. Ошибка в том, что Вы пишете в элементы массивов, но нигде не задаете размер массива. Задайте размеры (а Вы заранее их не знаете) либо используйте фунцию `push_back()` от вектора.

Comment: 4. На данном ресурсе уже много раз писали про то, как правильно пользоваться функциями типа `eof()` при считывании данных из файла. Например, можно воспользоваться способом [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762053/248924). В Вашем коде выражение `inputfile.eof()` в цикле сработает лишь после того, как Вы 3 лишних раза попытаетесь прочитать из файла (т.е. флаг состояния будет выставлен после первого неудачного чтения, но пока весь блок не закончится - цикл не остановит работу).

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я все-таки нашел ошибку, и она именно из-за попытки создать двухмерный массив. Я бы, конечно, не хотел уходить от двухмерного массива, потому что value[i][j] удобно использовать в for-циклах, которых будет ещё много.